# Console logging children from RSC and RCC gives different output

Tags: reactjs

I'm working in a NextJS project and I noticed a difference between Server Components and Client Components on how `children` work.

Assuming that I want to render `SmallComponent` inside `MainComponent`  which accepts `children` as prop.

```
function SmallComponent() {
  return <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
}

function MainComponent({ children }) {
  return <div>{ children }</div>
}

function Page() {
  return (
    <MainComponent>
      <SmallComponent />
    </MainComponent>
  )
}
```

No matter how I use, server or client, the output is the same result but if I do a `console.log(children)` in `MainComponent` I get this if I use it from the server side:

```
{
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: SmallComponent],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {},
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}
```

Instead if I change `MainComponent` to be executed on the client side the output is:

```
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: Symbol(react.fragment),
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {
    children: [
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}
```

The server says it is a function, it seems is not executed yet so the React component does not exist yet but it does when I use the component in the client.

I would like to know why it works in this way, is it not supposed that the server returns the generated HTML so the client only needs to execute the bundles that are for the client?

Comment: Are you sure that you log children in both places? The server one looks like you are logging <SmallComponent />, not children. Or you are passing a different children to each of them

Comment: @OktayYuzcan I updated the question, I just put the component I was rendering as `children`.

Comment: Where you put your console log? On client side it has type=react.fragment. I don't see any fragments here. Are you sure you are logging the correct thing?